# add select options to an existing selection field odoo 15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15

im trying to add more options to an existing selection field **(em_y)** depending on what's selected from another selection field **(em_x)** .
here is my code

```
from odoo import models,fields,api

class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit=['hr.employee']
    em_x = fields.Selection(selection=[('x A','x A'),('x B','x B')],string='X')
    em_y = fields.Selection([],string='Y')

    @api.onchange('em_x')
        def onchange_em_x(self):
            if self.em_x == 'x A':
                em_y = fields.Selection(selection_add = [('y A', 'y A'),('y B', 'y B')])
            elif self.em_x == 'x B':
                em_y = fields.Selection(selection= [('y C', 'y C'),('y D', 'y D')])
```

but this code is not working it display this

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py",
> line 643, in _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
> raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause ValueError: Wrong value for hr.employee.em_y: <odoo.fields.Selection>

can someone help me
THanks.

Comment: The error above is not the result of onchange function, in the onchange function you are just declaring a variable named `em_y`. The error is raised when setting the `em_y` field value (`self.em_y = fields.Selection`). You can't change the field definition from onchange function, instead, you can use a Many2one field, return a domain from onchange function and use the `selection` widget in the view definition.

Comment: i dont know how to do it exactly ,

Comment: can you help me with that pls

Comment: You can find an example in [smile_base_partner](https://github.com/Smile-SA/odoo_addons/blob/15.0/smile_base_partner/models/res_partner.py#L17) module which uses a domain based on values of a selection field (`company_type`, declared in `base` module)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible with "Selection" field. You must use "Many2one" field and in onchange method return domain.

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit=['hr.employee']

 em_x = fields.Many2one('em.x',string='X')
 em_y = fields.Many2one('em.x',string='Y',domain=[('id','=',0)])

@api.onchange('em_x')
def onchange_em_x(self):
    emx_a = self.env.ref('module_name.emx_a').id
    emx_b = self.env.ref('module_name.emx_b').id
    if self.em_x.id == emx_a:
        x_domain = [('id','in',[emx_a,emx_b])]
    elif self.em_x.id == emx_b:
        emx_c = self.env.ref('module_name.emx_c').id
        emx_d = self.env.ref('module_name.emx_d').id
        y_domain = [('id','in',[emx_c,emx_d])]

    return {'domain': {'em_x': x_domain,'em_y': y_domain}}

class EmX(models.Model):
    _name='em.x'
    
    name = fields.Char(string='Name',required=True)

#data.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="emx_a" model="em.x">
            <field name="name">A</field>
        </record>

        <record id="emx_b" model="em.x">
            <field name="name">B</field>
        </record>

        <record id="emx_c" model="em.x">
            <field name="name">C</field>
        </record>

        <record id="emx_d" model="em.x">
            <field name="name">D</field>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```